# catchError not working in angular refresh token

Tags: angular, refresh

I tried to show error message on 401 if refresh token call is failed but unable to get in catchError function. I have searched it but unable to find a useful solution. Before mark this as duplicate please first check if the solution works or not.

```
  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      const token = this.authService.getRefreshToken();
      if (token)
        return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
          switchMap((res: any) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access_token.token);
            localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", res.data.refresh_token.token);
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(res.data.access_token.token);
            return next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, res.data.access_token.token));
          }),
          catchError((err) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            
            this.authService.logout();
            return throwError(err);
          })
        );
    }

    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter(token => token !== null),
      take(1),
      switchMap((token) => next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token))),
    );
  }
```

switchMap works when i get a success it works fine but when i get error its not calling catchError function.

Comment: Hello
Could you share authService.refreshToken()?
What do you want to get? Error in console or any result in return?
Here is simpled example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqufze?file=src/interceptor.service.ts
Let me know, if I help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. Now i am getting error message on refresh token as well. CatchError works now here is the code

```
  if (refreshToken) {
    return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
      tap((accessToken) => {
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken.data.access_token.token);
        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", accessToken.data.refresh_token.token);
      }),
      switchMap((accessToken) => {
        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(accessToken.data.access_token.token);
        return next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, accessToken.data.access_token.token));
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        localStorage.clear();
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
        return throwError('Unauthorized');
      })
    );
  } else {
    this.isRefreshing = false;
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(["/"]);
    return throwError('Unauthorized');
  }
```